# Connection to Any one Data base in SpringBoot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way to load the respective hibernate config based on the property configured in a properties file.

I have an application to connect to Any database with the same schema through hibernate configs. Right now, I have created two hibernate configs One for DynamoDB another for all hibernate supported SQL's

I wanted to load only respective config by ignoring other config's.

i think we can specify like below

```
@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
```

Is it possible to create another property like profile.

Comment: you need to preset complete problem, we understand your application should be capable of connecting multiple databases but how many databases simultaneously,

Comment: Only one database at a time

Comment: you have got multiple suggestions in answeres to use profile, I would suggest creating a data-source class for each database and annotate them with @profile so that only required data source class will be initialized and loaded, rest things are already in answers

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple profiles active at the same time in your application.
So you can have profiles for specific databases along with the profiles responsible for environment type.

Then, you can define your properties in files called `application-dynamodb.properties` and `application-other.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use **@profile** concept here.You can maintain multiple properties file with different configuration and activate that specific configurations for example by adding 
**spring.profiles.active=dev** in application.properties, if **application-dev.properties** contains the required db configurations.But then you need to add @profile("dev") in configuration class while you are initializing/creating DB connection [working with profile](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1)